# Select rows which have only zeros in columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to select the rows in a dataframe which have zero in every column in a list of columns. e.g. this df:.

```
In: 
    df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3,6], [2,4,6,8], [0,0,3,4],[1,0,3,4],[0,0,0,0]],columns =['a','b','c','d'])
    df

Out:
    a   b   c   d
0   1   2   3   6
1   2   4   6   8
2   0   0   3   4
3   1   0   3   4
4   0   0   0   0
```

Then:

```
In:
    mylist = ['a','b']
    selection = df.loc[df['mylist']==0]
    selection
```

I would like to see:

```
Out:      
    a   b   c   d
2   0   0   3   4
4   0   0   0   0
```

Should be simple but I'm having a slow day!

Comment: Why is row 2 selected when it doesn't have zeros in every column?

Comment: because it has zeros in every column in `mylist`

Comment: ooh, didn't see that bit

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You'll need to determine whether *all* columns of a row have zeros or not. Given a boolean mask, use `DataFrame.all(axis=1)` to do that.

```
df[df[mylist].eq(0).all(1)]

   a  b  c  d
2  0  0  3  4
4  0  0  0  0
```

Note that if you wanted to find rows with zeros in every column, remove the subsetting step:

```
df[df.eq(0).all(1)]

   a  b  c  d
4  0  0  0  0
```

Comment: Great, but with `mylist` in place of `[a','b']`  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Using `reduce` and Numpy's `logical_and`
The point of this is to eliminate the need to create new Pandas objects and simply produce the mask we are looking for using the data where it sits.

```
from functools import reduce

df[reduce(np.logical_and, (df[c].values == 0 for c in mylist))]

   a  b  c  d
2  0  0  3  4
4  0  0  0  0
```